# Access to ArcObjects DLLs on a build server using Nuget

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, nuget

We're in the process of standing up a new build server--Jenkins on Windows Server 2012 if that matters--and are attempting to configure it to build a solution that uses ArcObjects (currently at 10.2.2, soon to upgrade to 10.4.1). In order to make the ArcObjects DLLs available to the build server we must install the ArcObjects SDK. In order to install the SDK we must install ArcGIS for Desktop, Server or Engine. Of course that software will never be used on this server so I'm looking for a way to swat our DLL fly without an ArcSledgeHammer.

I've considered circumventing the SDK on the server by tossing all ArcObjects DLLs into a nuget package on our internal repository. One down side of that would be duplicative references on development machines (which should still use the SDK). How great of a concern is that, and are there any other pitfalls to this solution?

We have at least five solutions that use ArcObjects:

- an extension to ArcMap that does all sorts of editing & querying,
- a server object extension,
- a small application that is used to find & open ArcMap from other custom in-house applications,
- another extension to ArcMap used for managing a specific dataset,
- a standalone application that has the ability to export a shapefile (no spatial awareness in that application that I'm aware of).

The first one contains over 20 `Esri.ArcGIS.Whatever` references, and all the others likely reference subsets of that.  The first one and others (but not all of them) are currently being built by Hudson running on an old desktop machine that has ArcMap installed on it (because it's used now & then).

Comment: You will probably have to use an ArcFlySwatter because it's impossible to hit a fly with an ArcSledgeHammer!

Comment: There's a third option -- ArcEngine can be installed as well.

Comment: What functionality do you need from ArcObjects?

Comment: @Brad see my edit.

Comment: that sounds like more than a "dll fly". Is all of this on the one server?

Comment: @Brad Yes, we've made significant use of ArcObjects here. But the server in question doesn't do GIS at all--it hosts our source control, our meager Nuget repo, and soon our build server; and that's all it does. To be clear, my goal isn't to avoid installing the SDK, but rather to avoid installing Desktop/Server/Engine. Our systems folks balked at the latter (in my estimation that's quite understandable) and I'm trying some due diligence before I tell them that it's necessary.

Comment: Since @Vince 's comment got some upvotes I want to point to my answer below for an explanation of why installing Engine didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a month of off & on tinkering, here's my wisdom (All Arc* software referenced below is version 10.4.1, and "the SDK" is shorthand for "the ArcObjects SDK"):

### The Short Answer

The path of least resistance is to install the SDK, which has two prerequisites:

- The product(s) against which you are developing (***full install***)
- A free flavor of Visual Studio supported by the SDK (and indeed ***required*** by the SDK installer)

### Showing My Work

I created a NuGet package of the needed DLLs in our on-site repo and consumed it in my test solution (the desktop extension with which I'm most familiar). This worked, but it created a confusing (at least to me) tangle of dependencies and strange warnings from MSBuild on my dev machine (stuff I did contradicted the SDK?). And so I abandoned the NuGet approach having never even checked those changes into source control, and I resigned myself to installing the SDK on the build server.  That re-requires Desktop, Server, or Engine; and I decided to install ArcEngine since it's the smallest. We installed Engine and re-tried the SDK install, but then received notification that Visual Studio must be installed so we installed Visual Studio Community 2015.  Installing the SDK then succeeded.

Our first build attempt failed with the message in the Jenkins console output: `"C:\Path\To\MyProject.csproj(1250,5): error MSB3073: The command "esriRegasm.exe "C:\Path\To\MyDll.dll" /p:Desktop /s" exited with code -1."`  Running that command directly on the server, we could see that the complete error was `Registration failed. Specified product is not installed`. Oh of course. If you're registering COM components with a particular product then that product must be available to be registered against. We uninstalled Engine and installed Desktop, and the build worked.  More details on the Desktop install:

- We custom-installed only the "Applications" icon. Everything else--including ArcCatalog and ArcMap--was excluded from the installation.
- We did not license it

***Edit:** After six more months during which I added more projects to Jenkins (including stuff that needed arcpy, which I neglected to install earlier), I found that you might as well do a full installation. Still no licensing needs for me but that may end up changing. At least that won't take re-installation.*

***Edit 2023:** In 2020, we began including unit & integration tests in some of the build jobs that involved ArcObjects. ArcGIS Desktop must be licensed on the machine running those tests. We use our concurrent license server for this, which means the tests fail in the (uncommon) event that no licenses are available.*

That describes the current state of ArcObjects on our new build server, but despite the functioning build I still wondered...
The SDK is needed on development machines, but what about on a build server?  The test build worked even after uninstalling the SDK, with the bare-bones Desktop install supplying all my needed DLLs and EsriRegasm.exe. But there are a couple DLLs available exclusively through the SDK (Addins, Addins.Factory, Desktop.Addins, and SoeSupport), and one anticipated future build is an SOE so we reinstalled the SDK. Another realization I made was that COM registration is needed at install time, not compile time--it's baked into SDK project templates primarily (I think) for working inside Visual Studio's debugger.

Taking those two observations together, all I need on the build server are DLLs. It seems a shop that's a little more savvy & a lot more determined (e.g. they must support multiple versions of Esri software at once?) ***could completely obviate Esri software on a dedicated build server*** by implementing the NuGet idea and removing the esriregasm calls in MyProject.csproj (or more likely conditioning them such that they aren't run on the build server but are still available to dev machines for debugging). My biggest concern would be that all that rigmarole could unduly confuse my successors (who will likely contend with plenty other sources of confusion): any new projects developed using the SDK's templates would have to be manually altered to remove/condition the COM registration out during builds.